# Understanding the complex-step in a physical sense

Tags: openmdao

I think I understand what complex step is doing numerically/algorithmically.

But the questions still linger. First two questions might have the same answer.

1- I replaced the partial derivative calculations of 'Betz_limit' example with complex step and removed the analytical gradients. Looking at the recorded design_var evolution none of the values are complex? Aren't they supposed to be shown as somehow a+bi?
Or it always steps in the real space. ?

2- Tying to picture 'cs', used in a physical concept. For example a design variable of beam length (m), objective of mass (kg) and a constraint of loads (Nm). I could be using an explicit component to calculate these (pure python) or an external code component (pure fortran). Numerically they all can handle complex numbers but obviously the mass is a real value. So when we say capable of handling the complex numbers is it just an issue of handling a+bi (where actual mass is always 'a' and b is always equal to 0?)

3- How about the step size. I understand there wont be any  subtractive cancellation errors but what if i have a design variable normalized/scaled to 1 and a  range of 0.8 to 1.2. Decreasing the step to 1e-10 does not make sense. I am a bit confused there.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to use complex arithmetic to compute derivative approximations is based on the mathematics of complex arithmetic. 
You should read about [the theory](http://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/content/complex-step-derivative-approximation-0) to get a better understanding of why it works and how the step size issue is resolved with complex-step vs finite-difference.

There is no physical interpretation that you can make for the complex-step method. You are simply taking advantage of the mathematical properties of complex arithmetic to approximate a derivative in a more accurate manner than FD can. So the key is that your code is set up to do complex-arithmetic correctly.

Sometimes, engineering analyses do actually leverage complex numbers. One aerospace example of this is the [Jukowski Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform). In electrical engineering, complex numbers come up all the time for [load-flow analysis](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-061-introduction-to-electric-power-systems-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_061S11_ch2.pdf) of ac circuits. If you have such an analysis, then you can not easily use complex-step to approximate derivatives since the analysis itself is already complex. In these cases, it is technically possible to use a more general class of numbers called [hyper dual numbers](http://adl.stanford.edu/hyperdual/Fike_AIAA-2011-886.pdf), but this is not supported in OpenMDAO. So if you had an analysis like this you could not use complex-step.

Also, occationally there are implementations of methods that are not complex-step safe which will prevent you from using it unless you define a new complex-step safe version. The simplest example of this is the [`np.absolute()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) method in the numpy library for python. The implementation of this, when passed a complex number, will return the asolute magnitude of the number:

```
abs(a+bj) = sqrt(1^2 + 1^2) = 1.4142
```

While not mathematically incorrect, this implementation would mess up the complex-step derivative approximation. 
Instead you need an alternate version that gives:

```
abs(a+bj) = abs(a) + abs(b)*j
```

So in summary, you need to watch out for these kinds of functions that are not implemented correctly for use with complex-step. If you have those functions, you need to use alternate complex-step safe versions of them. Also, if your analysis itself uses complex numbers then you can not use complex-step derivative approximations either.

With regard to your step size question, again I refer you to the [this paper](http://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/content/complex-step-derivative-approximation-0) for greater detail. The basic idea is that without subtractive cancellation you are free to use a **very** small step size with complex-step without the fear of lost accuracy due to numerical issues. So typically you will use 1e-20 smaller as the step. Since complex-step accuracy scalea with the order of step^2, using such a small step gives effectively exact results. You need not worry about scaling issues in most cases, if you just take a small enough step.